# Invisible or hidden XML element in SOAP service

Tags: java, cxf, jax-ws

I'm building an embedded JAX-WS SOAP service using Java. I'm defining my data types using `javax.xml.bind`.

I have a field in one of the data types that I'd like to be hidden, so that it will be supported but not be visible when a WSDL is published.

My motivation is that we are deprecating an attribute however I would to still support it (the contents will be ignored and unused). In the below example, if the user visits the WSDL at `http://myservice?wsdl` they will not see the attribute `email` as a part of `user`

Is there any annotation I can use that will provide this functionality? Alternatively

```
@XmlType
public class User
{
 @XmlElement
 public String name;

 @XmlElement
 @Hidden (?)
 public String email;

}
```

Comment: '@XmlTransient' is what you are looking for.
remove the '@XmlElement'

Comment: That doesn't work as expected. I still want the client to be able to submit the tag, I just don't want it visible when the WSDL is published.

Comment: `unexpected element (uri:"", local:"email")` is the error

Comment: That would be impossible. soap works with wsdl, if it is not there, it would not be marshalled as part of the document.

Comment: I don't see why it's impossible. Why can't a service genearte a WSDL but use a different marshaller.

Comment: its like saying i need my car driven, but hide the steering wheel. The wsdl defines a contract, you either comply with it or not.

Comment: I don't think that's an accurate analogy. Perhaps you don't understand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any standard way to tell CXF to ignore an element in the generated WSDL.  One option would be to maintain a static WSDL file, and then manually remove the "hidden" element from the schema.  You can leave the field in the JAXB annotated classes.  If you are configuring the service with Spring, you can add a WSDL with the wsdlLocation attribute:

```
<jaxws:endpoint 
    wsdlLocation="classpath:/Service.wsdl">
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Note that the XML containing the "hidden" fields would no longer validate, so you would need to ignore those errors, if you are using schema validation on the input messages.